# Xdebug with VSCode for PHP CLI don't attach

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, xdebug

I use Ubuntu 20.10

When I configure Xdebug for Visual Studio Code, I can debug from web site on browser, but when I launch a PHP command from CLI, the breakpoint was ignored.
I configured following the guide of Xdebug.

Comment: "I configured following the guide of xdebug" can you share the guide you have used? Also maybe point out which steps from it did you do and did work out for you. And at which step you got problems.

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` output (top table part) captured via CLI and via web page -- most likely they will show that 2 different php.ini config files are used (one for CLI and another for Apache). It's a pretty common thing these days on Linux and Mac. So .. check that and if it is the case the copy the same Xdebug config values to another config file.